# jquery plugin internal functions

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin

```
 (function($) {
        $.fn.myPlugin= function() {
           internalFunction();

           internalFunction = function() {

           };

    })($);
```

now I am trying to write a test to this plugin, is there a way to call internalFunction() from outside the scope of the plugin (i.e. $.fn.myPlugin.internalFunction() )

Thanks in advance